# crystal subreport field is blank in main report footer

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a subreport that has one group and has the following formula in Group Header 1
   WhilePrintingRecords;
   Shared StringVar TaskSubject := {activity_trans.subject}

My main report has the following formula in Group Footer 1
   WhilePrintingRecords;
   Shared StringVar TaskSubject;
   TaskSubject

When I drill into the detail section of my main report the field shows a value in the GF1 section but when I preview the main report the field is blank.

Comment: Perhaps provide us some source code?

Answer (score 0):

The problem with putting the formula in the Group Header is that you only get one record for the formula, which usually is the first record available. If that first record is blank, then you will see no data. Your formula is correct, but there may be an issue with the way you have structured your report or the data you are trying to display.

Comment: The purpose of my subreport is to bring back the most current record for the customer that has one to many relationship, so I do only what one record.  My subreport is returning the record I want and if I drill into the detail of the main report I see the record in the GF1 section.  But when I go back to the summary preview of the main report the field is blank.

Comment: So the value for the stringvar is actually coming from a subreport?

Comment: Yes, but I am having trouble getting it into the proper section of the main report.

Comment: When sharing variables, you have to make sure that a hierarchy is maintained. CR reads from the top down, so you have to declare a variable in a higher section (i.e. Report Header) for it to be read in a lower section (i.e. Group Header or Details).

Comment: So where do I need to place the subreport in order to get the shared variable to return to the main report Group Footer?  Currently my subreport is in the Main report Details.

Comment: Your subreport should be fine in the detail section if you want to return it in the group footer. In your question it says that you have it in the Group Header though, or am I misunderstanding something here?

Comment: I ended up creating a SQL view to do the same thing my subreport was doing.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: No problem, glad you were able to resolve your issue.